# Detecting which selected item (in a ListView) spawned the ContextMenu (Android)

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) that will allow the user to long-press an item to get a context menu. The problem I'm having is in determining which `ListItem` they long-pressed. I've tried doing this:

```
myListView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
  @Override public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, final View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
   menu.add("Make Toast")
    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
     @Override public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
      String toastText = "You clicked position " + ((ListView)v).getSelectedItemPosition();
      Toast.makeText(DisplayScheduleActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return true;
     }
    });
  } 
 });
```

but it just hangs until an [ANR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_not_Responding) pops up. I suspect that after the menu is created the `ListItem` is no longer selected.

It looks like you could monitor for clicks or long-clicks then record the clicked item there:

```
 mArrivalsList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  @Override public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
   // record position/id/whatever here
   return false;
  }
 });
```

but that feels majorly kludgey to me. Does anyone have any better solutions for this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I do exactly this. In my `onCreateContextMenu(...)` method, I cast the `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo` to `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo`. From there, you can get the targetView, which you cast again to the widget. The complete code is available in [HomeActivity.java](http://code.google.com/p/mood-log/source/browse/trunk/src/com/stuffthathappens/moodlog/HomeActivity.java), look for the `onCreateContextMenu(...)` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu,
                                View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
            (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    selectedWord = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
    selectedWordId = info.id;

    contextMenu.setHeaderTitle(selectedWord);
    contextMenu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT_ITEM, 0, R.string.edit);
    contextMenu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ITEM, 1, R.string.delete);
}
```

Note that I store the selected text as well as the select id in private fields. Since the UI is thread confined, I know the selectedWord and selectedWordId fields will be correct for later actions.

Comment: This is how I've done it also.  The key was figuring out that the ContextMenuInfo object was an instance of AdapterContextMenuInfo.  Took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: This will only work if the actual data behind the item is closely tied to the View created from the Adapter.  I've found this is often not the case with more complicated Adapters I've created (for example, it'll display an image and a name; clicking on it will open more details about the item, based on more data stored in the Adapter).

Comment: Excellent reply. Ditto on the figuring out that the ContextMenuInfo object was an instance of AdapterContextMenuInfo.

Comment: Can someone tell me why the info.id is the same as the position? shouldn't it be the ID given in the xml-resource?

Comment: This answer is too complicated. Consider the other answer.

Answer (score 68):

First of all, I'm wondering if you're making things a little overly complicated by using `View.setOnCreateContextMenuListener()`.  Things get a lot easier if you use `Activity.registerForContextMenu()`, because then you can just use `Activity.onCreateContextMenu()` and `Activity.onContextItemSelected()` to handle all of your menu events.  It basically means you don't have to define all these anonymous inner classes to handle every event; you just need to override a few Activity methods to handle these context menu events.

Second, there's definitely easier ways to retrieve the currently selected item.  All you need to do is keep a reference either to the `ListView` or to the `Adapter` used to populate it.  You can use the ContextMenuInfo as an AdapterContextMenuInfo to get the position of the item; and then you can either use `ListView.getItemAtPosition()` or `Adapter.getItem()` to retrieve the `Object` specifically linked to what was clicked.  For example, supposing I'm using `Activity.onCreateContextMenu()`, I could do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    // Get the info on which item was selected
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    // Get the Adapter behind your ListView (this assumes you're using
    // a ListActivity; if you're not, you'll have to store the Adapter yourself
    // in some way that can be accessed here.)
    Adapter adapter = getListAdapter();

    // Retrieve the item that was clicked on
    Object item = adapter.getItem(info.position);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Here's how you can get the correct item in onContextItemSelected()
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    Object item = getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
}
```

Comment: i have a question concerning your answer - how to do it if you have a listview widget in your xml layout file? i think then you can not overwrite the listactivity methods. how to listen to context menu clicks then? thanks in advance

Comment: I have a problem with your answer.My ContextMenuInfo menuInfo is always null. why ???

Comment: menuInfo is always null for me. Why ? (I use contextMenu on OnItemClick();)

Comment: OK, I just found why. Never forget to do opeContextMenu(v(theItem)) and not openContextMenu(v(theListview)).

Answer (score 4):

this is another way on how to create context menu n how to delete the item selected here is the whole code

```
     public class SimpleJokeList extends Activity {
public static final int Upload = Menu.FIRST + 1;
public static final int Delete = Menu.FIRST + 2;
int position;
ListView lv;
EditText jokeBox;
Button addJoke;
MyAdapter adapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
String jokesToBeAdded;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.simplejokeui);



    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.jokelist);
    addJoke=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addjoke);
    jokeBox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jokebox);


    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings);


    registerForContextMenu(lv);
    listItemClicked();
    addJokes();

private void addJokes() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    addJoke.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            jokesToBeAdded=jokeBox.getText().toString();
            if(jokesToBeAdded.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter some joke", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.add(jokesToBeAdded);
                jokeBox.setText(null);
            }   
        }
    });
}
private void listItemClicked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            position=arg2;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    populateMenu(menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select what you wanna do");

}
private void populateMenu(ContextMenu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     menu.add(Menu.NONE, Upload, Menu.NONE, "UPLOAD");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Delete, Menu.NONE, "DELETE");
}
 @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
     return (applyMenuChoice(item) || super.onContextItemSelected(item));
    }


private boolean applyMenuChoice(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {   
         case Delete:

             String s=mAdapter.getItem(position);
             mAdapter.remove(s);
            // position--;
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Congrats u HAve Deleted IT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return (true);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

And don't forget to put this

```
registerForContextMenu(listview);
```

in your `onCreate` method to get your context Menu visible.

Comment: Register before "listview.setAdapter(adapter)" if adapter is used.

Comment: @sami I am getting info null

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the view argument the actual selected row's view, or am I missing the question here?

```
ListView lv;
private OnItemLongClickListener onLongClick = new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        lv.showContextMenuForChild(arg1);
        lv.showContextMenu();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: The view argument is the ListView.

Answer (score 2):

We have used with success:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected
(
MenuItem item
)
    {
    if (!AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.class.isInstance (item.getMenuInfo ()))
        return false;

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo cmi =
        (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo ();

    Object o = getListView ().getItemAtPosition (cmi.position);

    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    View TargetV=(View) info.targetView;
    text1 = (String) ((TextView) TargetV.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText();
    text2 = (String) ((TextView) TargetV.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).getText();
    if(List3Ok){
        text3 = (String) ((TextView) TargetV.findViewById(R.id.textView3)).getText();   
    }
    selectedWord = text1 + "\n" + text2 + "\n" + text3;
    selectedWordId = info.id;
    menu.setHeaderTitle(selectedWord);
    MenuInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I case you are using `SimpleCursorAdapder` you may do it like this

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.project_list_item_context, menu);

    // Getting long-pressed item position
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int position = info.position;

    // Get all records from adapter 
    Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).getCursor();                     

    // Go to required position
    c.moveToPosition(position);

    // Read database fields values associated with our long-pressed item
    Log.d(TAG, "Long-pressed-item with position: " + c.getPosition());
    Log.d(TAG, "Long-pressed-item _id: " + c.getString(0));
    Log.d(TAG, "Long-pressed-item Name: " + c.getString(1));
    Log.d(TAG, "Long-pressed-item Date: " + c.getString(2));
    Log.d(TAG, "Long-pressed-item Path: " + c.getString(3));

    // Do whatever you need here with received values

}
```