# Pass object reference to menu item selection handler

Tags: android

I have a set of View instances that each represent some different data object (derived from Java.Lang.Object). I associate each view with its data object by setting the view's tag reference. The views can generate context menus, and in the onCreateContextMenu function I can get the source view and then get the data object from its tag.

My problem is that I can't find a way to associate the data object with the created menu or menu item such that I can get the data item in onContextItemSelected().

How do I propagate the data item to onContextItemSelected()?

**UPDATE**

From the link posted by @asktomsk it looks like what I want to do is only possible (without a lot of subclassing) if the originating view is a ListView. Having also read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) on the android developer site I suspect that long-tough context menus are probably not advisable anyway, and that I should find a different mechanism.

Comment: Try casting your object into desired type. You may also want to check the view type of your view. You can do so by getting the class's name by `yourViewObject.getClass().getSimpleName()`

Answer (score 0):

Check the [MenuItem.getMenuInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getMenuInfo%28%29) data. It contains information about context menu caller. 
Some explanation you may found here:

[Identifying the view selected in a ContextMenu (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926293/identifying-the-view-selected-in-a-contextmenu-android)