# How to get View in OnContextItemSelected event?

Tags: android

In public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo} event ,

I think I can know which control launch onCreateContextMenu event by the arg View v using the following, right?
ImageView imageview=(ImageView)v

But In public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item), I can't find the same arg, how can I do? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to find the position clicked from the context menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453620/android-how-to-find-the-position-clicked-from-the-context-menu)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
}
```

You can also get the exact View for which the menu is being displayed:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
    View view = info.targetView;
}
```

Look to these questions:

[Android: How to find the position clicked from the context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2453661/1043882)

[Identifying the view selected in a ContextMenu (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2926293/1043882)

Answer (score -1):

u can use

```
View v2;
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    v2=v;
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cnt_menu, menu);
  //  }
  }
```