# How to get the Button view which triggered a Context Menu?

Tags: android

I'm creating dynamically Button views with a context menu. When a context menu item is selected, I would like to retrive the Button view which triggered the context menu.

This is how I create the button :

```
// Create a new button
Button buttonView = new Button(this);
// Set button text
buttonView.setText("MyButton");
// Set on click listener
buttonView.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );
// Register for context menu
registerForContextMenu(buttonView);
```

This is how I create the context menu :

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

And this is how I handle selected items :

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Get extra menu information about the item selected   
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    // 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.delete:

        // Retrieve selected button text
        String btnText = ((Button) info.targetView).getText().toString();
        // etc...
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The issue is that "(AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()" returns null, i.e. there is no extra information about the item. I was expecting to get the Button view in info.targetView. Apparently this works only for ListView, because AdapterView takes care of populating this extra info.

I guess I should do something in "onCreateContextMenu" to attach this information. A sample code to attach this information would be very much welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Button` that was used to create the context menu is the `View` parameter passed into `onCreateContextMenu`.

Comment: Phil, how can I get the `Button` that was used to create the context menu into `onContextItemSelected` ?

Comment: @hleroy, it is already there. When you register a `View` (such as a `Button`) for the context menu: `registerForContextMenu(myButton);`, you allow the button to open a context menu when clicked. Then, in `onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)`, the `View v` is the button. You can check if the view that was selected was a certain button with something like: `if (v == myButton){ do something; }`

Comment: Hi Phil, I understand I can get the Button when the menu is created (i.e. into `onCreateContextMenu`). I need the Button when the item is selected (i.e. into `onContextItemSelected`).

Comment: @hleroy, you could save v to some local variable, such as `public View lastContextMenuButton` (or `public Button`), then in `onContextItemSelected` you can use `lastContextMenuButton`.

Comment: You're right: local variable should work. But I was hoping for a cleaner approach, i.e. setting menu info within `OnCreateContextMenu`, then geting the information via item.getMenuInfo() within `onContextItemSelected`. There is an internal class (`com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder`) which has a `setCurrentMenuInfo` method. ... But this is internal.

Comment: Does this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321332/detecting-which-selected-item-in-a-listview-spawned-the-contextmenu-android

Comment: This post doesn't help because `menuInfo` is `null` when view is a button. The Android doc says "`menuInfo`  Extra information about the item for which the context menu should be shown. This information will vary depending on the class of v.". When v is a `ListView`, menuInfo approach is fine. When it is a `Button`, it doesn't work. Anyway I have saved v into a local variable `public View lastContextMenuButton` as you suggested and I'm fine with that. I'm marking this issue as resolved.

Comment: @hleroy, I think exactly like you, and I think it's not a clean way to save the view in a local variable! I think It's totally reasonable to add information to menuInfo object, but seems it's not!