# fix java.lang.NullPointerException in the code

Tags: android-contextmenu

I am getting `NullPointerException` in the code for contextmenu.
here is the onCreateContextmenu Method

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit");
    menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE, 0, "Delete");
}
```

I am getting the error in the line  `long buttonId = info.id;` in the code below

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    long buttonId = info.id;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_EDIT:
            function1(buttonId);
            break;
        case MENU_DELETE:
            function2(buttonId);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can some one help me fix this

Comment: A stacktrace would be very helpful. It's likely that something is just null that's being passed in to one of the methods.

Comment: how to get stacktrace? I am a new and just started learning 2 weeks ago

Comment: @apgwoz can u guide me any tutorial or example showing context menu used for atleast two buttons? 
I have 8 buttons and need `EDIT` and `Delete` options for each

Comment: in function `onContextItemSelected` How can i get the id of the button that was long-pressed

Comment: @dmserazi: i don't know anything about android dev. I was just assuming the NullPointerException was caused by something simple... I assume the stack trace will show up in any logging that your emulator is providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` isn't passed to `onContextItemSelected` and

`AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    long buttonId = info.id;`

This code doesn't help because `menuInfo` is `null` when view is a `button`. The Android doc says "menuInfo Extra information about the item for which the context menu should be shown. This information will vary depending on the class of`v`". When `v` is a `ListView` `menuInfo`approach is fine. When it is a `Button`, it doesn't work.

In `onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)`, the `View v` is the `button` that produced the context menu. Copy`v` to a global `View` varaiable and use that where you need to have the view of the button that produced the context menu.

[How to get the Button view which triggered a Context Menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904394/how-to-get-the-button-view-which-triggered-a-context-menu)