# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ExpandableListView$ExpandableListContextMenuInfo

Tags: java, android, contextmenu, expandablelistview, classcastexception

I am really hoping someone will be able to help me here.
I am working off of this example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

And I am trying to capture which item invoked the contextMenu.
The only example I could find was here:

[Detecting which selected item (in a ListView) spawned the ContextMenu (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321332/detecting-which-selected-item-in-a-listview-spawned-the-contextmenu-android)

The only difference is that I have an ExpandableListView instead of a ListView.

When I use the example above from stackoverflow , I receive the following Exception:

```
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ExpandableListView$ExpandableListContextMenuInfo
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at com.frugalicious.android.CategoryList.onCreateContextMenu(CategoryList.java:121)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at android.view.View.createContextMenu(View.java:4362)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ContextMenuBuilder.show(ContextMenuBuilder.java:81)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.showContextMenuForChild(PhoneWindow.java:1880)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:460)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:460)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:460)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:1874)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at android.widget.AbsListView.access$600(AbsListView.java:74)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:1827)
02-25 21:08:27.271: E/AndroidRuntime(7812):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
```

I will provide any other information needed. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use the example above from stackoverflow , I receive the
>   following Exception

With above statement you mean you literally copy-pasted the answer on the linked question? If so, it's hardly surprising you get a ClassCastException. Try casting to a `ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo`, as the exception suggests in stead.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info =
            (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
   // ...
}
```