# Getting what is in a view on ContextMenuListener

Tags: android, android-view

How can I get, what is in the list item I long clicked on for a ContextMenu? I tried using `v.getTag()` but that return `null` all the time.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        clsStTwoLineAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (clsStTwoLineAdapter.ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
}
```

This is my ViewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        TextView text2;
        TextView text3;
        ImageView imgLineItem;
        int MessageID;
    }
```

Like I said `holder` is always `null`, so how else can I get what is in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [**post**](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/identifying-the-view-selected-in-a-contextmenu-in-oncontextitemselected-method/).

Comment: And [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2321332/844882).