# context menu not working

Tags: android

Hey guys I was looking at the 'Diaro' and the 'my Diary' app available on the Android market.
The items get displayed in a list view, and on long clicking an item, a context menu with various options(like edit, delete etc ) open up. I tried implementing the same in my app which is some what similar. But the problem is in the `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` I can't get the contents of the item clicked. Here's the code for `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.edit:


        break;v

          // rest of the codetion
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Can somebody tell me as to how can I get the id of the item clicked on the list view from this function? I can really use some help here:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must register yourView for contextMenu, like this :

```
list = getListView();
registerForContextMenu(list);
```

and you must use onCreateContextMenu for build it

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu,
                                View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
            (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    selectedWord = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
    selectedWordId = info.id;

    contextMenu.setHeaderTitle(selectedWord);
    contextMenu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT_ITEM, 0, R.string.edit);
    contextMenu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ITEM, 1, R.string.delete);
}
```

you have the listView item in your contextMenu title and it's id in selectedWordId

for more see this link : [Detecting which selected item (in a ListView) spawned the ContextMenu (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321332/1105277)

Comment: I don't have problem inflating the menu @Alish, the problem is this.The problem is that, if user clicks edit option in the context menu, how will the user get the rowId of the item clicked by thepublic void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) function

Comment: And by id I mean the id of the the items in  the list view,

Comment: you have data in database? or?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while and found out that I had onMenuitemselected() in my activity and this was listening to context menu item rather than on contextitemselected(), hope this helps.