# Sqlite Database RowId AutoIncrement after Deleting a Row

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Ok, I know this question has already been kinda answered on Stack but I didn't quite understand the answer and they didn't really answer the question at the end. My problem is that I have an app that uses a listview to display all my data from my database. There's an issue where when I delete a row from my table, the rowId auto-increment doesn't reset. I know this is normal but my app gets rows of data with my rowId and the only way that I've been able to get my rowId is to use the index of the selection of my listview. I can't get the text off the listView directly because the way I populated it was with a SimpleCursorAdapter. If the rowId no longer matches with the index of the listview there will be no way to get data from my database.

Is there a way to reset the rowId? I'm kind of new to sqlite so is there's a way to write your own autoincrement method? I just need a way to get data from my database from other activities and my activity with the listview.

My Get Row and Get All Rows Method:

```
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

My populate ListView method:

```
private void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID,DBAdapter.KEY_EVENT};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.saveStateID, R.id.saveStateEvent};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;

    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.layout_gt_listview, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);


    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    registerForContextMenu(myList);

}
```

Comment: "If the rowId no longer matches with the index of the listview there will be no way to get data from my database." - I'm not sure why you think that. You can always query with the row ID. The index isn't going to be of any use there.

Comment: how do I get the rowId of my selection from the onclick listener of my list view?

Comment: It's the fourth parameter in `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`'s [`onItemClick()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView<?>,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)). The `long` is the row ID in a `ListView` with a `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: ooooohh...I'm dumb. Thank you, I'm kind of new to listviews/sqlite.

Comment: No problem. Slight correction: The `long` is actually whichever column you're using as the `_id` for the `CursorAdapter`. That's not necessarily always the `rowid`, but for any column that's `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, they're the same thing. Just a minor nitpick.

Comment: ummm any ideas on how to do this in a Context Menu?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321332). Several answers there show how to get an `AdapterContextMenuInfo` object for a list item, both when the menu is created, and when a menu item is selected. The `id` field of `AdapterContextMenuInfo` is what you want.

Comment: works! thanks again!